# How to filter duplicate elements and create new array?

Tags: swift, filter

I have a duplicate elements array

```
let array = [1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 3, 6]
```

How to filter this array and create new array like this:

```
[[1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [5], [6]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite easy, you should try with this:

```
let array = [1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 3, 6]

let result= Set(array).map{ value in return array.filter{$0==value} }

print(result)
```